# The created mpdf is not getting uploaded in the server folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

I am creating a pdf using mpdf in a codeigniter project. But I am getting an error saying

> mPDF error: Unable to create output file:
>   /var/www/html/bm/ecomtest/application/assets/upload/invoice/myfile.pdf

The folder invoice on the server has full permission of 777. My code in the controller is:

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = [];
        //load the view and saved it into $html variable
        $html=$this->load->view('admin/payments/viewinvoice', $data, true);


        $pdfFilePath = APPPATH."assets/upload/invoice/myfile.pdf";

        //load mPDF library
        $this->load->library('m_pdf');

       //generate the PDF from the given html
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);


        $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "f");        
    }
```

If I change the code into `$this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");` it generates the pdf.
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have all the requirements for mPDF to work:

> PHP >= **5.6.0** and < **7.3.0**.
>
> PHP **mbstring** (including **mbregex**, which needs to be explicitly enabled in some environments) and **gd** extensions have
>   to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the entire path like this:

```
$mpdf->Output('c:/xampp/htdocs/your-project/assets/test.pdf',\Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);
```